# Encountering Unreachable statement in switch case while implementing Firebase Auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, switch-statement

"Statement not reachable under the switch case for signing out using the button in menu item. "

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sign_out_menu:

                AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this); //NOT REACHABLE
                return true;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: elaborate your question.

Comment: It's because of the return statment above swithc `return super.onOption...` remove it or place it under switch.

Comment: You should add some details for explanation of problem

Comment: I am sorry! 
I had added a screenshot, it didn't show up for some reason I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

write this line at the end of method
"return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first line in the method `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); // Remove this line

    switch(item.getItemId()){

    }
}
```

Because you have a return statement in your code, everything under the 1st `return` statement which is not part of the `switch` is not reachable

Answer (score 0):

you can use either return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); or just true; after ending switch case, don't forget break; statement too.

```
int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.id1:
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId()  , fragment1);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.id2:
            Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager1.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction1.replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId()  , fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction1.commit();
            break;            

    }

    return true;
```

Comment: explain your answer please

Comment: you can use method "return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);" or just true after end of switch case and dont forget to break statement; this two statements gives not reachable error.